# Importing data(columns) from CSV file to elastic search

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, spring-boot, java-8

I am working on importing columns from CSV file to elastic search,can anyone help me finding the exact query and requirements to load the data to elastic search from csv.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use filebeat and logstash.

Filebeat read your csv file and send to logstash.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-installation.html

Logstash parse your data ( it can csv parse ) and send to elasticsearch.

Logstash csv input:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html

Answer (score 0):

You can load CSV to ES using this python script:

```
import csv
from elasticsearch import helpers, Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
with open('file.csv') as f:
    r = csv.DictReader(f)
    helpers.bulk(es, r, index='index_name', doc_type='doc_type')
```

This will do bulk insert for all the rows in a CSV file to elasticsearch. If you want to insert in a bulk of 100 items or so, you can make a counter and insert 100 items at a time.

PS: For Java, you can look at this library [here](https://github.com/AgileWorksOrg/elasticsearch-river-csv).

Comment: where should i write this python script?

Comment: you should write the script in the same folder, where your csv is placed. Else, you can specify the write path of your CSV at line no. 4.

Comment: I loaded my csv to elastic ,important thing here is i have to mention sincedb path as well!

Comment: Can you show how to implement the counter for 100 rows or more?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [**duckimport**](https://github.com/ofarukcaki/duckimport), it's a global npm module and available on all platforms.

Ps. I'm the developer